# Which is asymptotically larger:(lgn)^lg(lgn) or [lg(lgn)]^lgn

Tags: performance, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Which is asymptotically larger: (log n)<sup>log(log n)</sup> or [log(log n)]<sup>log n</sup>?

I took the logarithm on both sides and was confused to judge which one is greater among the two.

Comment: Try taking the log of both sides twice.  It may become more clear.  After the first taking of logs, the left side becomes: log(log(n))*log(log(n)) or log(log(n))^2 while the right side becomes log(n) * log(log(log(n))).  The second iteration yields for the left side: 2*log(log(log(n))) and for the right side, log(log(n)) + log(log(log(log(n)))).  Asymptotically, the term log(log(n)) on the right side should dominate all other terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let a = log n, b = log log n = log a

a<sup>b</sup> / b<sup>a</sup> = (e<sup>b</sup>)<sup>b</sup> / e<sup>((log b) * e<sup>b</sup>)</sup> = e<sup>(b<sup>2</sup>)</sup> / e<sup>(log b * e<sup>b</sup>)</sup>

so comparing b<sup>2</sup> vs e<sup>b</sup> * log b, I think b<sup>a</sup> is the larger one, since log b is eventually larger than one.

Answer (score 0):

With LibreOffice Calc 3.6.4.3:

- the first exceeds Calc's number limit (Error `#NUM!`) with n=21
- the latter results in 3,12E+053 for n=21 and exceeds Calc's number limit with n=40

Answer (score 0):

A) lg (lg * n)
B) lg * (lg n)

As per the definition of lg *, we can write B as

lg * (lg n) = lg * n - 1.

So, A is asymptotically lower than B.